# moveit_tutorial build failing

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the step here:
https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#install-moveit

- ROS Version: Melodic
- OS: Ubuntu 18

It works till catkin configure.
After the catkin build command the panda_moveit_config finished without errors but the moveit_tutorials gives me erros.
The build log shows the following

```
[  5%] Built target robot_model_and_robot_state_tutorial
[ 11%] Built target ros_api_tutorial
[ 17%] Built target planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial
[ 23%] Built target planning_scene_tutorial
[ 29%] Built target motion_planning_api_tutorial
[ 35%] Built target motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial
[ 47%] Built target interactivity_utils
[ 52%] Built target move_group_interface_tutorial
[ 58%] Built target state_display_tutorial
[ 61%] Building CXX object doc/subframes/CMakeFiles/subframes_tutorial.dir/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp.o
[ 67%] Built target pick_place_tutorial
[ 73%] Built target cylinder_segment
[ 79%] Built target bag_publisher_maintain_time
Scanning dependencies of target trajopt_example
Scanning dependencies of target visualizing_collisions_tutorial
[ 85%] Built target controller_manager_example
[ 88%] Building CXX object doc/trajopt_planner/CMakeFiles/trajopt_example.dir/src/trajopt_example.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object doc/visualizing_collisions/CMakeFiles/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.dir/src/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.cpp.o
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/visualizing_collisions/src/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.cpp:47:10: fatal error: moveit/collision_detection_fcl/collision_env_fcl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <moveit/collision_detection_fcl/collision_env_fcl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
doc/visualizing_collisions/CMakeFiles/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'doc/visualizing_collisions/CMakeFiles/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.dir/src/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.cpp.o' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4490: recipe for target 'doc/visualizing_collisions/CMakeFiles/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [doc/visualizing_collisions/CMakeFiles/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.dir/src/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [doc/visualizing_collisions/CMakeFiles/visualizing_collisions_tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp: In function ‘void spawnCollisionObjects(moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface&)’:
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:114:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   box.subframe_names.resize(5);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:115:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses.resize(5);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:117:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   box.subframe_names[0] = "bottom";
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:118:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[0].position.y = -.05;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:119:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[0].position.z = 0.0 + z_offset_box;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:123:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[0].orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:126:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   box.subframe_names[1] = "top";
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:127:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[1].position.y = .05;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:128:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[1].position.z = 0.0 + z_offset_box;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:130:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[1].orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:132:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   box.subframe_names[2] = "corner_1";
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:133:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[2].position.x = -.025;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:134:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[2].position.y = -.05;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:135:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[2].position.z = -.01 + z_offset_box;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:137:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[2].orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:139:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   box.subframe_names[3] = "corner_2";
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:140:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[3].position.x = .025;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:141:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[3].position.y = -.05;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:142:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[3].position.z = -.01 + z_offset_box;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:144:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[3].orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:146:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   box.subframe_names[4] = "side";
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:147:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[4].position.x = .0;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:148:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[4].position.y = .0;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:149:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[4].position.z = -.01 + z_offset_box;
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:151:7: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   box.subframe_poses[4].orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:169:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   cylinder.subframe_poses.resize(1);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:170:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   cylinder.subframe_names.resize(1);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:171:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_names’
   cylinder.subframe_names[0] = "tip";
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:172:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   cylinder.subframe_poses[0].position.x = 0.03;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:173:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   cylinder.subframe_poses[0].position.y = 0.0;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:174:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   cylinder.subframe_poses[0].position.z = 0.0 + z_offset_cylinder;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            plane_poses
/home/pyro/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/subframes/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp:176:12: error: ‘moveit_msgs::CollisionObject {aka struct moveit_msgs::CollisionObject_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘subframe_poses’; did you mean ‘plane_poses’?
   cylinder.subframe_poses[0].orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            plane_poses
doc/subframes/CMakeFiles/subframes_tutorial.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'doc/subframes/CMakeFiles/subframes_tutorial.dir/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [doc/subframes/CMakeFiles/subframes_tutorial.dir/src/subframes_tutorial.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4783: recipe for target 'doc/subframes/CMakeFiles/subframes_tutorial.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [doc/subframes/CMakeFiles/subframes_tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
[ 94%] Linking CXX executable /home/pyro/ws_moveit/devel/.private/moveit_tutorials/lib/moveit_tutorials/trajopt_example
[ 94%] Built target trajopt_example
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333021/moveit_tutorial-build-failing/) by [pyropotato](https://answers.ros.org/users/45624/pyropotato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on 2019-09-23**:
Seems like the same as [this issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1669).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you build moveit from source beforehand?

https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#create-a-catkin-workspace-and-download-moveit-source was updated just two days after your question...

---

Originally posted by [jschleicher@Pilz](https://answers.ros.org/users/46057/jschleicher@pilz/) with karma: 56 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pyropotato](https://answers.ros.org/users/45624/pyropotato/) on 2019-09-29**:
tried again([link text](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html#create-a-catkin-workspace-and-download-moveit-source))  but gives other errors.

I was however able to install it by following these instructions:
[https://moveit.ros.org/install/source/]